# Upload video file to amazon S3 after FFMPEG conversions - Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

I'm trying to upload file to s3 using ffmpeg, and its creating a 0B file, what could be the reason behind this?

My Code is as follows:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.config('medialibrary.s3.domain').'/listing_video/intromain.mp4'.' -vf "drawtext=fontfile='.storage_path('assets/video/FutuMd.ttf').': text='.$listing->car->name.': x=680: y=500: fontsize=55: fontcolor=white: enable=\'between(t,4,6)\'" '.Storage::put('intromainfinal.mp4', '').'');
```

Comment: When saving file locally, does it's still provides 0B?

Comment: @Justinas not sure, I'm trying and that and will tag you again.

Comment: @Justinas it works properly in Local

Comment: ffmpeg needs to be able to seek in the output MP4. Does S3 allow that?